# Cannot get two objects united with Json.parse and Json.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I have a doubt about how to unite to objects and give them in a express response in node js.

The object is like this:

```
{
    "idP": 1,
    "pasaporteNum": 787643682,
    "fidP": 1,
    "fid_p": 1
}
```

The other one also:

```
{
    "idP": 1,
    "pasaporteNum": 827348,
    "fidP": 1,
    "fid_p": 75683475
}
```

So the code is something like:

```
var a = JSON.stringify(context.instance[0].dataValues)
var b = JSON.stringify(context.instance[2].dataValues)
 res.send('{'+JSON.parse(a+','+b)+'}')
```

Why I receive this error?

```
 "Unexpected token , in JSON at position 53"
```

At the end I need something like:

```
{
    "idP": 1,
    "pasaporteNum": 787643682,
    "fidP": 1,
    "fid_p": 1
},
{
    "idP": 4,
    "pasaporteNum": 456789,
    "fidP": 2,
    "fid_p": 2
}
```

regards

Comment: I think you need `res.send([context.instance[0].dataValues, context.instance[2].dataValues])`

Comment: that is the shortest correct answer

Comment: try just `console.log(a+','+b)` and you should see where the mistake is, why it is not a valid json object.

Comment: check this fiddle this might help. https://jsfiddle.net/5L2ywjy9/1/

Comment: You really want to stringify before passing an object to `res.send`, if you're using Express you could do it directly with `res.json( object )` instead

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you have two objects with the same properties, you probably just want to add those to an array before stringifying

```
var arr = [context.instance[0].dataValues, context.instance[2].dataValues]

res.send( JSON.stringify( arr ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a `JSON` format and send from your api, so you need not `JSON.parse()` but `JSON.stringify()`.

```
var a = JSON.stringify(context.instance[0].dataValues);
var b = JSON.stringify(context.instance[2].dataValues);
res.send('{' + JSON.stringify(a + ',' + b) + '}');
```

Answer (score 0):

with your format, you want an array instead of an object . 
res.send('['+JSON.parse(a+','+b)+']')

or simpler you can do

```html
JSON.stringify([context.instance[0].dataValues,context.instance[2].dataValues])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.stringify()` and `.parse()`, Just as create an array and send it.

```
res.send([context.instance[0].dataValues, context.instance[2].dataValues])
```